# Replace each variable with specific values associated to them

Tags: python, pattern-matching, artificial-intelligence

For a university's project I'm developing an inference engine written in Python and I'm trying to introduce in it all the features that Clips has, one of them is variables.

Actually, in the grammar I provide a way in order to specify a condition in a rule which has got variables in it using the '?' character. In particular, I can have a rule defined in this way:

```
(rule (father ?x ?y) then (assert (parent ?x ?y))
```

Supposing that in the working memory there are these facts:

```
(father John Tom) (father John Liz) (father Alex Mat) (father Alex Andrew)
```

with the defined rule we will assert these facts simply doing some variable pattern matching:

```
(parent John Tom) (parent John Liz) (parent Alex Mat) (parent Alex Andrew)
```

This is the situation in which I am and actually I'm able to correctly match each variable to all its possible values which are present in the WM.

In this case I create a dictionary whose keys are the variables's identifier (?x or ?y) and whose values are all values present in the WM which could be associate to the variables
`(e.g {?x:[John, Alex], ?y:[Tom, Liz, Andrew]})`

My question is:
how can I correctly dispose all the variables' possible values in the correct manner in order to get all the facts that should be asserted?

Thank you in advance,

Alessandro Suglia

Comment: From the dictionary, you *can't* - you have lost the pairing, there is no way to tell that John is Tom and Liz's father but Alex is Andrew's father. You need to rethink your data structure - perhaps two-tuples?

Comment: I've not understood why I can't use the dictionary. I can make some kind of combinations of all the possible values.
If I have three variables [x,y,z] and for each of them I have two possible values I will obtain eight possible solutions.
Is it wrong what I've said?

Comment: But not all of those combinations are true! `(father John Liz) (father Alex Mat)` does *not* mean `(parent John Mat)`

Comment: Yes sure. 
In fact I don't want exactly combinations, but I need some kind of disposition.
I've thought about a tree of possible solutions starting from a specific value of the first variable, but I'm not able to reproduce it correctly and also I think that it's not the best solution at all.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
bank = { ("John","Tom"): ("father", "parent"),
         ("John","Liz"): ("father", "parent"),
         ("Alex","Mat"): ("father", "parent"),
         ("Alex","Andrew"): ("father",)}

x = ("John", "Alex")
y = ("Tom","Liz","Mat","Andrew")

def assert_then_xy(trait1, trait2):
    for my_x in x:
        for my_y in y:
            if (my_x,my_y) in bank.keys():
                if trait1 in bank[my_x,my_y] and not trait2 in bank[my_x,my_y]:
                    print "{} {} is a {}, but not a {}".format(my_x,my_y,trait1,trait2)
            else:
                print "{} {} could not be located".format(my_x,my_y)

>>> assert_then_xy("father", "parent")
John Mat could not be located
John Andrew could not be located
Alex Tom could not be located
Alex Liz could not be located
Alex Andrew is a father, but not a parent
>>> assert_then_xy("parent", "father")
John Mat could not be located
John Andrew could not be located
Alex Tom could not be located
Alex Liz could not be located
>>>
```

Comment: It's wrong. 
If you have more than two variables it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to the problem using a recursive function that I briefly describe here for future question about the topic.

```
def substitute_var_rec(solutions, var_dict, curr_list, missing_var, var_index):
'''
    solutions: list which contains all the correct combinations generated
    curr_list: list which contains the current combination
    missing_var: variables not yet replaced
    var_index: variables' position in the pattern (a dictionary whose keys are variables'
    identifier and which has as values a list of index)

'''

# if the current combination doesn't contains variable 
# we have finished the construction of the current combination
if not has_variable(curr_list):
    # add it to the solutions' list
    solutions.append(curr_list[:])

else:
    next_var = missing_var[0]  # take the next variable to be examined
    for val in var_dict[next_var]:
        index = var_index[next_var]
        if isinstance(index, list):
            for curr_index in index:
                curr_list[curr_index] = val
        else:
            curr_list[var_index[next_var]] = val
        substitute_var_rec(solutions, var_dict, curr_list, missing_var[1:], var_index)


def substitute_variable(fact, var_dict):
    '''
        fact: a list which contains the fact's name and its attributes
        var_dict: mapping between variables' identifiers and their values
    '''
    pattern = fact[1:]  # a list which contains the pattern to be filled with variables' values
    variables = [x for x in pattern if x.startswith('?')] # takes variables's identifier
    if len(variables) > 1: # different variables in fact
        first_variable = variables[0] 
        all_solutions = []

        # generates a dictionary which contains the variables' position in the pattern
        var_index = {}
        for i in range(len(pattern)):
            if pattern[i].startswith('?'):
                if pattern[i] in var_index:
                    if isinstance(var_index[pattern[i]], list):
                        var_index[pattern[i]].append(i)
                    else:
                        var_index[pattern[i]] = [var_index[pattern[i]], i]
                else:
                    var_index[pattern[i]] = i

        curr_list = pattern[:]

        # starting from the first variable
        # explore all its values and generate all the combinations
        for val in var_dict[first_variable]: 
            index = var_index[first_variable]
            if isinstance(index, list):
                for curr_index in index:
                    curr_list[curr_index] = val
                var_index[first_variable] = index[1:]
            else:
                curr_list[var_index[first_variable]] = val
            substitute_var_rec(all_solutions, var_dict, curr_list, variables[1:], var_index)
            var_index[first_variable] = index
            curr_list = pattern[:]

        return all_solutions
    else:
        var_index = list(pattern).index(variables[0])
        solutions = []

        for val in var_dict[variables[0]]:
            solutions.append([pattern[i] if i != var_index else val for i in range(len(pattern))])

        return solutions
```

Thank you to everyone who have answered to this question.
If you have some suggestions about the code I really appreciate them.

Cheers,

Alessandro Suglia